# Как вызвать глобальную функцию объявленную в html из bundle

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

Мне нужно вызвать функцию, содержимое которой генерируется php из кода js, скомпилированного webpack

Использую webpack 4

// html страница, сгенерированая php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.launchHandler = function() {
        // динамическое содержимое

    }
</script>
```

// app.js (bundle)

```
if (typeof window.launchHandler != 'undefined') {
    window.launchHandler();
}
```

Но при вызове window.launchHandler из app.js всегда получаю undefined, т.к область window в webpack другая. Как передать реальный window в webpack?

Comment: _т.к область window в webpack другая_ это откуда такие мысли? Может у вас сначала загружается скрипт, а потом объявляется функция? window для скриптов один ( за исключениями всякий афйреймов/св )

Comment: Да, сначала скрипт, потом функция. Но обращение к функции помещено document ready. Поместить функцию выше скрипта нет возможности.

Comment: не уверен, что `document.ready` тут помогает